# Apply a custom theme on a LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'd like to apply a whole custom theme on a LinearLayout.

I'm using the SlidingMenu of https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu and I'd like to apply the Hol theme while the rest of the application would be in Holo.Light.

My actual styles.xml contains :

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>

<style name="SlidingTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
</style>
```

My code to attach the sliding menu is :

```
    // configure the SlidingMenu
    SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(activity);
    menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
    menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    menu.setBehindWidth(200);
    menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    menu.attachToActivity(activity, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
    menu.setMenu(R.layout.slidingmenu);
```

How can I apply my theme to my LinearLayout ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  style="@style/SlidingTheme" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="187dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_group"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_action_group"
    android:text="@string/customer"
    style="@style/SlidingTheme" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My goal is to apply the style (holo dark) to only the SlidingMenu or my linearlayout (and its content). I have the feeling I can't apply that on my LinearLayout.

Comment: What's your question or problem?

Comment: well you are right, it isn't clear. i'll edit the question

Answer (score 1):

You can apply themes to **Activities** or **Fragments**, or even to the whole **application**.
This is done inside the **AndroidManifest.xml** file.
So, do something like this in your manifest:

```
<!-- Apply the common theme for the whole application -->
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.your_theme"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    >
    <!-- ... -->
    <!-- This activity has its own theme -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.your_company.your_app.your_other_activity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.your_other_theme"
    />
```

Comment: Well the problem is that I don't want to apply it to a Activity but to the SlidingMenu which contains a LinearLayout and I don't know how to do this. any idea ?

Comment: Can this sliding menu be contained into an activity? If so, it's done. Move all into an activity that contains it.

Comment: I don't think it is possible :(

Comment: But... wait a minute! what are we talking about? You **can't** theme a single widget, even if it is a container (they call them layouts, but aren't **layout files**). You better give it colors inside your layout file. But then, a layout file is applied to an activity or a fragment, which **can** be themed. This SlidingMenu you're talking about SHOULD be contained somewhere. THAT "somewhere" can be themed.

Comment: the sliding menu is attached to the activity and isn't an activity neither a fragment. it is like a control which can be hide or showed. (if i didn't misunderstand) I think i will have to modify the background and the different properties ..

Comment: So, finally, it " is attached to the activity" (by your words). So THAT ACTIVITY can be themed. And the sliding menu will inherit the theme (or it has its own theming methods, maybe?).

Comment: well i'm rly sorry if it isn't clear. i'd like to have a different theming on the other activity. the answer is : i can't using the theming feature for that case. I thank you for your time